# jquery.post in a wordpress plugin, Directory issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have some jQuery post code that throws a not found error when I try and run it. I am trying to run it as part of my wordpress plugin, I know the files are in the same directory but and it is spelt correctly. I have tried accessing the file directly from url and adding that url to the plugin but I then get error 500.

From the research I have done I think there is something I have to do to add this file in my plugin, I think it has something to do with it not being in the wordpress framework but I cant find any solutions to my issue.

```
jQuery.post("getResults.php", {id:id} , function(data)
        {
            jQuery("select#kDate").removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("select#kDate").html(data);
        })
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function(xhr, status, detail) { alert("error ("+status+") : " + detail); })
     });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works by using the full url of the file if you get an error 500 internal server error try changing your permissions, as that worked for me. This code is for wordpress.

```
jQuery.post("<?php echo plugins_url("/race-results/getResults.php"); ?>", {id:id} , function(data)
        {
            jQuery("select#kDate").removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("select#kDate").html(data);
        })
        .success(function() { alert("success"); })
        .error(function(xhr, status, detail) { alert("error ("+status+") : " + detail); })
     });
```